# Is there any Pandas way to add a comma at the end of the each row in a csv generated by .to_csv() method?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I am generating a csv file from a pandas dataframe with below code-

```
full_df.to_csv("../output.csv", quotechar='"', quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL, index=False, columns=['ProductId','SkuId','EAN','Brand'])
```

The requirement is to put double quotes in header as well as in values also and it is working as expected.
But here I need to add a comma also in the last of each row due to some requirement; so I updated my code as below-

```
full_df.to_csv("../output.csv", quotechar='"', quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL, index=False, columns=['ProductId','SkuId','EAN','Brand',''])
```

But it is adding double quotes after the comma also, some snippet of generated csv in notepad++ format is as below-

```
"ProductId","SkuId","EAN","Brand",""
"17447","17447-562","7390000000000.0","Champion",""
```

Below is the expected result-

```
"ProductId","SkuId","EAN","Brand",
"17447","17447-562","7390000000000.0","Champion",
```

Is there any way to achieve this without re-iterating the csv since original csv has more than 70k records?

Comment: What is the "some requirement"?

Comment: can you explain why the result you get doesnt work?

Comment: Well it's a hack but it should work. Add a new empty column and then output it to csv: `df[np.nan] = np.nan`

Comment: In `to_csv` there is an option called `line_terminator`, I guess if you change its value from the default `\n` to `,\n` it might do the trick.

Comment: @ysearka thanks a lot! I use it and it just worked. My issue is solved now.

Comment: You're welcome! And since @jezrael solution works, don't hesitate to accept his answer to close the question! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use solution by [@yesarka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966316/is-there-any-pandas-way-to-add-a-comma-at-the-end-of-the-each-row-in-a-csv-gener/51966392#comment90882661_51966316):

```
full_df = pd.DataFrame({'ProductId':list('abcdef'),
                   'SkuId':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'EAN':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'Brand':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (full_df)
  ProductId  SkuId  EAN  Brand  E  F
0         a      4    7      1  5  a
1         b      5    8      3  3  a
2         c      4    9      5  6  a
3         d      5    4      7  9  b
4         e      5    2      1  2  b
5         f      4    3      0  4  b

a = full_df.to_csv(quotechar='"', 
               quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL, 
               line_terminator = ',\n',
               index=False, columns=['ProductId','SkuId','EAN','Brand'])
print (a)
"ProductId","SkuId","EAN","Brand",
"a","4","7","1",
"b","5","8","3",
"c","4","9","5",
"d","5","4","7",
"e","5","2","1",
"f","4","3","0",
```

Comment: yes @jezrael, I did this and my problem is solved. Thank you also for sharing the example.